# Omitting variables in Sparql changes results

Tags: sparql

I'm querying some data from the [Sparql endpoint](http://data.consilium.europa.eu/sparql) of the public records of the votings of the Council of European Union.

Currently, I want to get session and act numbers for recorded votes, which I can achieve with this query:

```
PREFIX codi: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/def/codi/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX ecv: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/data/public_voting/rdf/schema/>
PREFIX qb: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/data/public_voting/qb/dimensionproperty/>

SELECT ?recordedVote ?sessionNumber ?act ?actNumber 
WHERE {
   ?recordedVote a <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#Observation>.
   ?recordedVote qb:sessionnrnumber ?session.
   ?session skos:prefLabel ?sessionNumber.
   ?recordedVote qb:act ?act.
   ?act skos:prefLabel ?actNumber 

}
LIMIT 10
```

Note that `LIMIT 10` is there only to speed up execution during testing the query. Here are the results:
[image]

However, I have to include `?act` in the select list, otherwise the results are wrong:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is not "wrong", they're both correct answers: they give you a subset of 10 solutions of all results that match the query.

The reason you're getting different solutions in your result is that the SPARQL endpoint optimizes the query execution differently when you leave `?act` out of the `SELECT` clause. It probably switches to a different internal index, and returns  solutions in a different order. If you were to leave out the limit, you'd see that both results are the same, just in a different order.

You can fix this by forcing a specific order to your query, with an `ORDER BY` clause. For example:

```
PREFIX codi: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/def/codi/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX ecv: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/data/public_voting/rdf/schema/>
PREFIX qb: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/data/public_voting/qb/dimensionproperty/>

SELECT ?recordedVote ?sessionNumber ?act ?actNumber 
WHERE {
   ?recordedVote a <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#Observation>.
   ?recordedVote qb:sessionnrnumber ?session.
   ?session skos:prefLabel ?sessionNumber.
   ?recordedVote qb:act ?act.
   ?act skos:prefLabel ?actNumber 

}
ORDER BY ?act
LIMIT 10
```

and

```
PREFIX codi: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/def/codi/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX ecv: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/data/public_voting/rdf/schema/>
PREFIX qb: <http://data.consilium.europa.eu/data/public_voting/qb/dimensionproperty/>

SELECT ?recordedVote ?sessionNumber ?actNumber 
WHERE {
   ?recordedVote a <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#Observation>.
   ?recordedVote qb:sessionnrnumber ?session.
   ?session skos:prefLabel ?sessionNumber.
   ?recordedVote qb:act ?act.
   ?act skos:prefLabel ?actNumber 
} 
ORDER BY ?act
LIMIT 10
```

will return the same result (minus a column, of course).

Comment: Thank you very much. :)